Wrong type argument: symbolp, 'yas-minor-mode
Whenever I type, Emacs gives me the warning 'wrong type argument: symbolp, 'yas-minor-mode'.

You've messed up some yasnippet configuration probably. To find out where, do M-x toggle-debug-on-error and when you get the backtrace, add it to your question. You will probably want to turn off yas-minor-mode everywhere while you figure out the breakage: C-u -1 M-x yas-global-mode will disable the global mode. You can also toggle the mode in each individual buffer with M-x yas-minor-mode.
